# How to mock angular.module('myModule', []).value() in Jasmine/Protractor

Tags: angularjs, mocking, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm trying to use Protractor's addMockModule() to mock a simple AngularJS module and override a variable:

Here is my HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div  ng-controller="myAppController">    
        Overriden module value <b>{{myValue}}</b>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/Lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/module.js"></script>
    <script src="/controller.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['myModule']);

myApp.controller("myAppController", function ($scope, myValue) {
    $scope.myValue = myValue;
});
```

Here is my Module:

```
var newModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
newModule.value('myValue', "oldValue");
```

Here is my Jasmine/Protractor code:

```
var mockMyModule = function () {
        var newModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
        newModule.value('myValue', "newMockedValue");
    };

    it('should override services via mock modules', function () {

        ptor = protractor.getInstance();
        ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.addMockModule('portfolioDataAccessMod', mockMyModule);
        browser.get('http://localhost:57627/page1.html');

        expect(element(by.binding("myValue")).getText()).toBe("newMockedValue");

    });
```

Results:

Failures:

> 1) End-to-end test in /AssetAllocation/Index  should override
>   services via mock modules    Message:
>        Expected 'oldValue' to be 'newMockedValue'.

What is wrong ?

All samples I have found so far are to override HTTP calls, but all I want is to mock a very simple module with a simple variable. Is it possible to do in Protractor ?

Comment: The idea behind this is to have constants for live environment, and change them just for protractor test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Juliemr in this post:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/509

> " the code that is run in the mockedModule is run in a separate
>   context from the test. One is in the browser, one is in the node.js
>   process running the test "

**Put declaration of `mockedValue` inside `it()` and enable angular synchronization**

```
it('should override services via mock modules', function () {
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();

    // When ignoreSynchronization is true mocking doesn't work
    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = false; 

    browser.addMockModule('myModule', function () {
        var module = angular.module('myModule').config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
            $provide.constant('myValue', 'newMockedValue');
        }])
    });

    browser.get('http://localhost:57627/page1.html');
    expect(element(by.binding("myValue")).getText()).toBe("newMockedValue");

});
```

Comment: It's normal that it doesn't work. With ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true; you are specifying that you are not testing an angular page. So there is no need to mock.

Comment: More on ignoreSynchronization attribute here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808463/what-is-browser-ignoresynchronization-in-protractor