# Change value module.value() on the Protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I have a system using AngularJS and I'm using Protractor to test,  however, would like to change a value set in module.value().

The module is thus:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myModule');

app.value('config',{
logo: 'images/logo.png',
apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/v1/', ...
```

In tests I tried it (not this going right):

```
beforeEach(function() {

    var mockedModule=function(){
        var module = angular.module('myModule').value('config',{
                apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/v1/'
        });
    };

    browser.addMockModule('myModule',mockedModule); 

});
```

I want to know how can I change the value in "apiUrl" in the tests?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mockedModule = angular.module('myModule', []).config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('apiUrl', 'http://localhost:8080/v1');
  }]);

browser.addMockModule('mockedModule', mockedModule);
```

Reference: [How to mock angular.module('myModule', []).value() in Jasmine/Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542895/how-to-mock-angular-modulemymodule-value-in-jasmine-protractor)